# How do I create a GraphQL API that resolve to a cypher query?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graphql, agens-graph

I am designing an API for a prototype project we have created that uses [AgensGraph](http://bitnine.net/agensgraph/) as the graph database. Now that we have a working graph database, we need an API (RESTful or GraphQL) that can be used to query the graph without directly using a cypher query. I am looking into using GraphQL. It appears that Neo4j has [a GraphQL to Cypher resolver](https://github.com/neo4j-graphql/neo4j-graphql/blob/3.3/readme.adoc). Is there a similar way to create a GraphQL API for AgensGraph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing that I'm aware but ...

- There is a graphql plugin for postgres, and AgensGraph is based on PG
- you can fork the neo4j-graphql-js project, and change the driver. This project is a Cypher generator for a GraphQL schema, but it uses Neo4j as a backend.

Otherwise try Neo4j :)